# Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while launching the app using appium

Tags: appium-android

My code is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJwm5.png)

My pom.xml does have dependencies like org.seleniumhq.selenium (4.13.0) and appium (8.6.0):

I was trying to open app, but I get the below error:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
FAILED: open
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<init>(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)'
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.<init>(AppiumClientConfig.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.defaultConfig(AppiumClientConfig.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:113)
    at openapp.open(openapp.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Please add code as text, not as an image.

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodError` generally means that you're combining incompatible versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your Appium java client version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```